# understanding three.js ray projection

Tags: three.js

I want to understand how ray projection works. Almost where ever I see, I get a code like this:

```
new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0.5);
```

I'm confused about the 0.5 in the z position. As per my understanding we are projecting on to `z=1 plane` (not `z=0.5 plane`). So shouldn't we be using it like this instead?

```
new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 1.0);
```

Comment: You may find my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23492823/746754 useful as it goes into ray projection and the z component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern often used is like this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5,
);
```

This is a point in Normalized Device Coordinate (NDC) Space.

The function

```
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
```

is mapping from NDC space to world space.

The value `0.5` for `vector.z` can be set to any value between -1 and 1.

Why? Because these points are all on a line parallel to the z-axis in NDC space, and will all map to the same ray emanating from the camera in world space.

Setting `z = -1` will map to a point on the near plane; `z = 1` the far plane.

So the short answer is, it doesn't matter what the value of `z` is, as long as it is between -1 and 1. For numerical reasons, we stay away from the endpoints, and 0.5 is often used.