# Project a 2D screen point to 3D world point

Tags: three.js

I saw the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z) and I have problems to understand the subtruction of the camera position from the ray direction
followed by adding the result to the camera position.
Can someone please add a vector diagram that explains what these operations do?

Thanks,
Avner

Answer (score 0):

I posted the answer [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/project-a-2d-screen-point-to-3d-world-point/5713) based on the very useful illustration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036106/three-js-projector-and-ray-objects)